# Host ASP.NET Web API with hostname and IIS at the same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to host a Web API self host application along with IIS.

My Web API project is running on `subdomain1.domain.com`. My IIS have a site configurered at `subdomain2.domain.com`.

As soon as my Web API application is started it takes over everything on port 80 and responds to it - no matter what the hostname is. Is it possible run these to sites side-by-side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the port in the `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` constructor. See the code here for an example: http://www.matlus.com/self-host-asp-net-web-api/

*Edit to specify further answer from comment: `selfHostconfiguration.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;` will allow running the sites on the same port.

Comment: I am well aware that I can change the port. But I want my  public API running on port 80 as well as my site. But different hostnames.

Comment: Ahhh...in that case did you try taking a look at the `HostNameComparisonMode`? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.hostnamecomparisonmode(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! Used `selfHostconfiguration.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;` and now my IIS and selfhost app runs side-by-side!

Comment: Don't know if you should maybe update your answer with the correct response in the comment :)